# Multilabel classification with imbalanced dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, multilabel-classification

I am trying to do a multilabel classfication problem, which has an imabalnced dataset.
The total number of samples is 1130, out of the 1130 samples, the first class occur in 913 of them. The second class 215 times and the third one 423 times.

In the model architecture, I have 3 output nodes, and have applied sigmoid activation.

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(256, 256, 3))
base_model = VGG16(input_tensor=input_tensor,weights='imagenet',pooling=None, include_top=False)

#base_model.summary()

x = base_model.output

x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

x = tf.math.reduce_max(x,axis=0,keepdims=True)

x = Dense(512,activation='relu')(x)

output_1 = Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')(x)

sagittal_model_abn = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output_1)

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = True
```

I am using binary cross entropy loss, which I calculate usng this function.
I am using weighted loss to deal with the imbalance.

```
        if y_true[0]==1:
            loss_abn = -1*K.log(y_pred[0][0])*cwb[0][1]
        elif y_true[0]==0:
            loss_abn = -1*K.log(1-y_pred[0][0])*cwb[0][0]
        if y_true[1]==1:
            loss_acl = -1*K.log(y_pred[0][1])*cwb[1][1]
        elif y_true[1]==0:
            loss_acl = -1*K.log(1-y_pred[0][1])*cwb[1][0]
        if y_true[2]==1:
            loss_men = -1*K.log(y_pred[0][2])*cwb[2][1]
        elif y_true[2]==0:
            loss_men = -1*K.log(1-y_pred[0][2])*cwb[2][0]

        loss_value_ds = loss_abn + loss_acl + loss_men
```

`cwb` contains the class weights.

`y_true` is the ground truth labels having length 3.

`y_pred` is a numpy array with shape (1,3)

I weight the classes individually as occurrence and non-occurrence of the classes.

Like, if the label is 1, I count it as an occurrence and if it is 0, then it is a non-occurrence.

So, the first class's label 1 occurs 913 times out of 1130

So the class weight of label 1 for the first class is 1130/913 which is about 1.23 and the weight of the label 0 for the first class is 1130/(1130-913)

When I train the model, the accuracy oscillates (or stays almost same), and the loss decreases.

And I am getting predictions like this for every sample

`[[0.51018655 0.5010625  0.50482965]]`

The prediction values are in the range 0.49 - 0.51 in every iteration for all the classes

Tried changing the number of nodes in the FC layer but it still behaves the same way.

Can anyone help?

Does using `tf.math,reduce_max` cause the problem? Should using `@tf.function` to do the operation that I am doing using `tf.math.reduce_max` be beneficial?

**NOTE**:

I am weighting the labels 1 and 0 for each class separately.

```
cwb = {0: {0: 5.207373271889401, 1: 1.2376779846659365}, 
       1: {0: 1.2255965292841648, 1: 5.4326923076923075}, 
       2: {0: 1.5416098226466575, 1: 2.8463476070528966}}
```

**EDIT**:

The results when I train using `model.fit()`.

```
Epoch 1/20
1130/1130 [==============================] - 1383s 1s/step - loss: 4.1638 - binary_accuracy: 0.4558 - val_loss: 5.0439 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.3944
Epoch 2/20
1130/1130 [==============================] - 1397s 1s/step - loss: 4.1608 - binary_accuracy: 0.4165 - val_loss: 5.0526 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5194
Epoch 3/20
1130/1130 [==============================] - 1402s 1s/step - loss: 4.1608 - binary_accuracy: 0.4814 - val_loss: 5.1469 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.6361
Epoch 4/20
1130/1130 [==============================] - 1407s 1s/step - loss: 4.1722 - binary_accuracy: 0.4472 - val_loss: 5.0501 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5583
Epoch 5/20
1130/1130 [==============================] - 1397s 1s/step - loss: 4.1591 - binary_accuracy: 0.4991 - val_loss: 5.0521 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.6028
Epoch 6/20
1130/1130 [==============================] - 1375s 1s/step - loss: 4.1596 - binary_accuracy: 0.5431 - val_loss: 5.0515 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5917
Epoch 7/20
1130/1130 [==============================] - 1370s 1s/step - loss: 4.1595 - binary_accuracy: 0.4962 - val_loss: 5.0526 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.6000
Epoch 8/20
1130/1130 [==============================] - 1387s 1s/step - loss: 4.1591 - binary_accuracy: 0.5316 - val_loss: 5.0523 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.6028
Epoch 9/20
1130/1130 [==============================] - 1391s 1s/step - loss: 4.1590 - binary_accuracy: 0.4909 - val_loss: 5.0521 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.6028
Epoch 10/20
1130/1130 [==============================] - 1400s 1s/step - loss: 4.1590 - binary_accuracy: 0.5369 - val_loss: 5.0519 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.6028
Epoch 11/20
1130/1130 [==============================] - 1397s 1s/step - loss: 4.1590 - binary_accuracy: 0.4808 - val_loss: 5.0519 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.6028
Epoch 12/20
1130/1130 [==============================] - 1394s 1s/step - loss: 4.1590 - binary_accuracy: 0.5469 - val_loss: 5.0522 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.6028
```

Comment: I think you should not weight the different classes between them. You should weight the label 0 and 1 for each class. For example:
For your first class your label for 0 should be  1130/913 and the label for 1 should be 1130/217 (217=1130-917).
For the second class: label 1's weigth is 1130/215, etc...

Comment: @federicober I did exactly that. I weighted the label 0 for the first class with 1130/217 and the label 1 with 1130/913, since label 1 occurs 913 times and 0 occurs 217 times.

Comment: Have you tried with 3 separate classifiers?

Comment: @federicober I will try and tell you within a few hours.

Comment: @federicober The outputs are still  like this `[[0.49103534]] [[0.48069718]] [[0.50579894]]`. The outputs are near about 0.5, this means the input to the sigmoid is almost ZERO. The weights are not zero, I checked.

Answer (score -1):

I would try the label powerset method.

Instead of 3 output nodes, try setting that to the total number of combinations possible as per your labels and dataset. For example, for a multi-label classification with 3 distinct classes, there are 7 possible outputs.

Say, labels are A, B and C. Map output 0 to A, 1 to B, 2 to C, 3 to AB, 4 to AC and so on.

Using a simple transformation function before training and for testing, this problem can be converted to a multi-class, single label problem.

Comment: The dataset is an imbalanced multilabel one. Oversampling one class may also oversample other classes associated with it. The link you gave is for a multi-class classification problem